# in excel connecting with ODBC while debugging I get error ORA-00942 table or view does not exist

Tags: excel, odbc

We have move to a cloud-based system and are having troubles running this script it errors out at   **objMyRecordset.Open**. this worked before we moved to a cloud based system.

Function loadIDList()

```
    Dim objMyConn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim objMyCmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim objMyRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim s As String

    Set objMyConn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set objMyCmd = New ADODB.Command
    Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset

    objMyConn.ConnectionString = "[Provider=MSDASQL;] Driver= Oracle in instantclient_19_9;DSN=XXXX;UID=xxxx;PWD=XXXXXXX;"
    objMyConn.Open

    Set objMyCmd.ActiveConnection = objMyConn
    
    s = "select ID, EPLANT_ID from LEGACY_SCHEDULE order by ID asc"

    objMyCmd.CommandText = s
    objMyCmd.CommandType = adCmdText

'Open Recordset'
    Set objMyRecordset.Source = objMyCmd
    objMyRecordset.Open

    IDList = objMyRecordset.GetRows
    objMyRecordset.Close
```

I have checked the table names and all see valid. I even changed then to Caps to match the tables that I'm connected to.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.